# Adding in if statement for add form to make edit form usable

Tags: php

I have one form that is used to add and edit something. On the form is a select tag. What I'm asking is where do I use an if statement in this to see if its the edit then to preselect a value preset for the form.

Example below is what is needed for general add form:

```
<select name="item_status" id="select1" class="nostyle" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select Status">
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach($something AS $item)
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$item->item_id.'">'.$item->items_name.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="item_status" id="select1" class="nostyle" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select Status">
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach($something AS $item)
    {
    $selected = $_REQUEST['item_status'] === $item->item_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$item->item_id.'"'.$selected.'>'.$item->items_name.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```